# PHP escapeshellarg messing up my password

Tags: php, encoding

```
$passphrase = "';__!!??()[]";

$passphrase = escapeshellarg($passphrase);
shell_exec("openssl\openssl.exe genrsa -des3 -passout pass:${passphrase} -out test.key 2048");

#Here the password works
echo system("openssl\openssl.exe rsa -in test.key -passin pass:${passphrase} -noout -text");
```

This code works fine to generate a key with openssl. I can also read the key without any problem. But when I want to read the key from the command line I'm unable to decrypt it. I use exactly the same command as in the code. The only difference is, that I copy the passphrase to the command line as it is written in the code. This always fails with a bad decrypt error.

How can I fix this issue?

Edit: To make this more clear. This does not work when run from terminal:

```
openssl\openssl.exe rsa -in test.key -passin pass:"';__!!??()[]" -noout -text
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the command you execute that doesn't work? Just `... pass:';__!!??()[] ...`?

Comment: I edited the question to show the command not working.

Comment: You should escape it the same way `escapeshellarg` does, you're likely just messing up the shell syntax: `pass:''\'';__!!??()[]'`

Comment: When I create the RSA key manually from the terminal with the same password this works fine without manually escaping. I want to make sure the user can use exactly the same key that he typed in to decrypt the key from terminal.

Comment: Write the password to a file and use the -kfile option of openssl.

Comment: @MarceloStaudt Thanks for the idea with -kfile. When reading the password from a file everything works like a charm.

Comment: Just remember to delete the file after. You don't want a password stored in plain text anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use PHP's OpenSSL library instead of the shell?

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php